# URL rewriting in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can I use the following snippet,

```
var MSG = $("#message").val();
var dataString = 'message='+ MSG;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "InsertMessage?message="+MSG,
    data: {message:MSG},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        $(".content").prepend(data);
        $("#message").focus();
    }
});
```

I want to send a parameter to servlet to add to the database `data: {message:MSG},` sends an empty parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `#message` element you're wanting to send the text of is just a standard `div`, then you need to use `text()` instead of `val()`:

```
var MSG = $("#message").text();
```

`val()` is mostly used for form elements such as `input`, `select`, etc.

Comment: I have input field

Comment: In that case, what's the output of `console.log($("#message").val())`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove data. It is no longer needed since you passed the parameter in the URL in GET. Make sure the URL is accessible and the parameter is correctly handled by the Request parameter in your servlet.

Comment: To access the parameter in servlet, use <HttpServletRequest var>.getParameter.(<request parameter name>)

Comment: e.g. req.getParameter(message);